# Does ActiveScaffold work with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin, scaffolding, activescaffold

Does ActiveScaffold work with Rails 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ActiveScaffold github page](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold) readme now lists Rails 3.0 - 3.2 support, which was based on further development of vhochstein's fork.

Answer (score 4):

This fork has rails 3 support https://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold/wiki